# Unable to parse string quoted csv data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to parse this CSV data which has quotes in between in unusual pattern and semicolon in the end of each row.

I am not able to parse this file correctly using pandas.

Here is the link of data (The pastebin was for some reason not recognizing as text / csv so picked up any random formatting please ignore that)

https://paste.gnome.org/pr1pmw4w2

I have tried using the "," as delimiter, and normal call of pandas dataframe object construction by only giving file name as parameter.

```
header = ["Organization_Name","Organization_Name_URL","Categories","Headquarters_Location","Description","Estimated_Revenue_Range","Operating_Status","Founded_Date","Founded_Date_Precision","Contact_Email","Phone_Number","Full_Description","Investor_Type","Investment_Stage","Number_of_Investments","Number_of_Portfolio_Organizations","Accelerator_Program_Type","Number_of_Founders_(Alumni)","Number_of_Alumni","Number_of_Funding_Rounds","Funding_Status","Total_Funding_Amount","Total_Funding_Amount_Currency","Total_Funding_Amount_Currency_(in_USD)","Total_Equity_Funding_Amount","Total_Equity_Funding_Amount_Currency","Total_Equity_Funding_Amount_Currency_(in_USD)","Number_of_Lead_Investors","Number_of_Investors","Number_of_Acquisitions","Transaction_Name","Transaction_Name_URL","Acquired_by","Acquired_by_URL","Announced_Date","Announced_Date_Precision","Price","Price_Currency","Price_Currency_(in_USD)","Acquisition_Type","IPO_Status,Number_of_Events","SimilarWeb_-_Monthly_Visits","Number_of_Founders","Founders","Number_of_Employees"]

pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=",", encoding="utf-8", names=header)
```

Comment: what is the issue/error?

Comment: The issue is, data is not being parsed correctly, because of the weird pattern of quotes and commas. Here is a quick look at the output :- https://pasteboard.co/Ixpbd3z.png

Comment: Line 2 is blank which doesn't match the csv header

Comment: Did not got you, can you please suggest a script for this one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can just read the data normally. Now all data would be in the first column. You can use pyparsing module to split based on ',' and assign it back. I hope this solves your query. You just need to do this for all the rows.

```
import pyparsing as pp
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
df.loc[0] = pp.commaSeparatedList.parseString(df['Organization Name'][0]).asList()
```

Output

```
df #(since there are 42 columns, pasting just a snipped)
```

[image: data after assigning]

Comment: This approach seems really nice, I have doubt about the ";" in the end. I suspect they are not included in the data, they should be removed ?

Comment: @gaurav1999 you can remove it after your convert like this (Using regex replace or string substitute). That should not be an issue.

Comment: This solution breaks, when I add more rows to data.

Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 42 fields in line 64, saw 81

Not sure which row's causing it.

Comment: I have one more general solution though, which let's me parse csv easily without any worries and does not breaks on some cases like this.

Here:- https://paste.gnome.org/pypgx1qzy

But the problem with this solution is that this solution gives me each row in string. Now I seek to convert this data in pandas dataframe. Any suggestions in that regard ?

Comment: @gaurav1999 each row as just one string or list of strings (of length 42, since there are 42 columns)?

Comment: that solution gives me complete row as a single string, not list of strings.
The data where the provided solution breaks for example is:- https://paste.gnome.org/paa6awqhl
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 46 fields in line 5, saw 56

To me it seems like this kind of data is not readable by using that technique, a corner case always appears and breaks it.